# How to duplicate list and operate differently?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am doing a problem, like word ladder.
   Originally I have a string list: `paths = [[A]]`. 
   Now B, C and D are all strings which have only one different letter compared
   to A. What I wish to do is to make

```
[[A]] with [B,C,D] ->  paths = [[A,B], [A,C], [A,D]]
```

But if I copy the `[[A]]` threes tames to prepare `paths = [[A], [A], [A]]` 
   using `paths = [paths[0]]*3`, then then doing:

```
i=0
for word in [B,C,D]:
    newpath = paths[i]
    paths.append(newpath.append(word))
    i += 1
```

which shows `[[A, B, C, D], [A, B, C, D], [A, B, C, D]]`. It seems the same operation on each copy. Even though I used `paths = [paths[0] for i in range(3)]`, it is still the same. How can I avoid it? What's wrong with my code?

A ton of thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python list of lists, changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: I tried the method. See I tried "paths = [paths[0] for i in range(3)]",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `paths = [paths[0] for i in range(3)]`, `paths[0]` is still a reference to one and the same list. You probably want `paths = [paths[0].copy() for i in range(3)]`.

You can put the following code to [pythontutor visualization](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html) to check how it works:

```
paths = [['A']]
paths = [paths[0] for i in range(3)]
otherpaths = [['A']]
otherpaths = [otherpaths[0].copy() for i in range(3)]
```